# Deleting specific record by making delete function

Tags: php

One my page i call  this delete function

```
$Sql=mysql_query("SELECT Id FROM products");
    $Result=mysql_fetch_row($Sql);
    $Id=$Result[0];
    DeleteRecords("products","Id",$Id)
```

on functions.php i made this function below

```
function DeleteRecords($Table,$Exp,$Value)
{
if(isset($_GET['delete']))
{
$Sql="DELETE FROM $Table WHERE $Exp=$Value";
$Result=mysql_query($Sql);
if($Result)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Record Deleted')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.location='products.php';</script>";    
    }
}
}
```

Now when i am clicking the delete link:

```
<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?delete=$Id'>Delete</a>
```

Its delete the first row. seems there is some problem with $Id

Please help me how to delete my selected row;

the best would be all the things should be done in functions i have to just call function on my page!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: Dude I just started learning php i dont even know mysql completely how can i jump over it !

Comment: Dude we're here to teach you the *right* way

Comment: I saw the link of tutorial ...its going above my head :S actually as of yet i only can do add edit delete update :) just started learning... and the article written on that tutorial i cannot understand :S new ?? is this OOP ...

Comment: @RaheelExile There is no problem with MySQL. The problem is with the `mysql_` functions, which are outdated (and in the close future might be removed), but a lot of old tutorials teach them. You should not learn them at all, learn mysqli or PDO.

Comment: You don't "*jump over it*". It's just another way to query the database. The functions you're using are no longer maintained, fixed etc. So if you are starting fresh anyway, `mysqli` or `PDO` are good ways to do so.

Comment: @RaheelExile If you are afraid of OOP, start with mysqli. It can be used either in a procedural or OOP way. But please, don't learn `mysql_` stuff...

Comment: oh means i dont have to change any thing except functions ? the query method would be the same ?

Comment: @RaheelExile mysqli has a lot of very similary functions. But you should start learning with prepared statements, it should save you from the doom of SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select all products:

```
$Sql=mysql_query("SELECT Id FROM products");
```

Then you assign the id of the first element to `$Id`:

```
$Id=$Result[0];
```

Then you pass `$Id` to your function - the same value is called `$Value` there:

```
DeleteRecords("products","Id",$Id)
```

Finally in your function you check whether `$_GET['delete']` is set. And if it is, you use the `$Id` from the first element of the result before in the delete query (instead of the passed value in `$_GET['delete']`:

```
$Sql="DELETE FROM $Table WHERE $Exp=$Value";
```

So you never use the value of `$_GET['delete']`.

---

You could write:

```
 DeleteRecords("products","Id", $_GET['delete']);
```

and in the function:

```
$Value = intval($Value);

if (0 != $Value) {
    $Sql="DELETE FROM $Table WHERE $Exp=$Value";
    $Result=mysql_query($Sql);
    […]
```

This is at least some sort of preventing a SQL injection. Not suitable for all situations, but a starting point. There's a nice website about ["Bobby Tables"](http://bobby-tables.com) that can give you more information about that.

Comment: Can you please send me the corrected code ? Its first time i m making functions so i m lacking concepts ! however my delete isset is working fine when i mouseover my delete link its showing the correct id in url but on click it deletes the first row of the table

Comment: and what should i put instead of $Id on my page ?

Comment: @RaheelExile I assume your link is generated by a loop over all products and it's a unqiue link for each product? In this case you don't have to change anything.

Comment: yes each row there is a loop generated delete link with in a while loop 
<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?delete=$Id'>Delete</a>

Comment: actually i have an understanding that if function delete ($var1,$var2,$var3) then when i call function i have to define all three parameters.. like i did products,Id,$Id ... the code you gave me i put it in my functions.php page.... but now i m asking about how to call this function

Comment: what should i pass to $value ?

Comment: See my answer: `DeleteRecords("products","Id", $_GET['delete']);`.

Comment: Its working fine but its showing this notice on my page 
Notice: Undefined index: delete in C:\xampp\htdocs\E-commerce\products.php on line 125
i treid doing $Id=$_Get['delete']; still showing